# Should Semaphoreslim be in the controller instead of further down in the chain?

Tags: c#, semaphore, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a deadlock like behaviour in our production-environment and I wonder if we use `SemaphoreSlim` correctly.

In our restapi the code looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromBody] SomeModel someModel)
{
    var result = await _someClass.CreateArende(someModel);

    return result;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAsync([FromBody] SomeModel someModel)
{
    var result = await _someClass.RegisterArende(someModel);

    return result;
}
```

No `SemphoreSlim` in controller level of our API but in someClass looks like this:

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    protected static SemaphoreSlim _semphoreSlimCreateArende = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public async virtual Task<SomeResponseDto> CreateArende(SomeModel someModel)
    {
        try
        {
            await _semphoreSlimCreateArende.WaitAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                _semphoreSlimCreateArende.Release();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        return new SomeResponseDto()
        {
            ...
        };
    }

    public async virtual Task<SomeResponseDto> RegisterArende(SomeModel someModel)
    {
        try
        {
            await _semphoreSlimCreateArende.WaitAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                _semphoreSlimCreateArende.Release();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        return new SomeResponseDto()
        {
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Should the `SemaphoreSlim` be in the controller level instead? Or should I change the controllers actions to not be async?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little disjointed, however lets try to make sense of it a little

**Firstly** lets get the pattern right

```
try
{
    await _semphoreSlimCreateArende.WaitAsync();

    // do your sync work here

}
finally
{
    // if this throws you are certainly doing something wrong
    _semphoreSlimCreateArende.Release(); 
}
```

**Secondly**, you should have your keyboard taken away from you for this

```
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Don't ever blindly eat exceptions, and if you are getting them on `_semphoreSlimCreateArende.Release` you have serious problems already and you have to work out why

> Should the semaphoreslim be in the controller level instead?

Use them at the level that makes the most sense, i mean if you need to sync a piece of code sync it there, not 13 levels up.

> Or should i change the controllers actions to not be async?

if you have `asnyc` work make your controller `async` and let it propagate down the stack to your `async` code

> We have a deadlock like behaviour in our production-environment and i
> wonder if we use semaphoreslim correctly.

Woah, are we talking DataBase Deadlocks, or Context DeadLocks. Either way this all sounds a little fishy

Comment: ”Using a SemaphoreSlim in a web based service can be a nasty approach.” - What is best practice in async code for a web based solution? Google async lock c# and semaphoreslim shows up

Comment: I've needed to run one of my controller method synchronous since it uses com api which should be executed over one request at a time. I've chosen SemaphoreSlim over lock keyword in my controller and it works great.